# SafeRestart - Jenkins CLI command is throwing exception in windows 10

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I am getting below exception while i try to execute the below command:

java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ safe-restart

```
ERROR: Unexpected exception occurred while performing safe-restart command.
hudson.lifecycle.RestartNotSupportedException: Default Windows lifecycle 
does not support restart.
    at hudson.lifecycle.Lifecycle$1.verifyRestartable(Lifecycle.java:84)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.safeRestart(Jenkins.java:4216)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.doSafeRestart(Jenkins.java:4176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
```